# How to bind data between two different ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two input fields with different ng-model name, how do i bind these two data.

```
<input ng-model="trip.name" type="text">
<input ng-model="customer.name" type="text">
```

i want the data filled in "trip.name" auto-filled in "customer.name",
How should i proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-change` directive to achieve this. The html would look like

```
<input ng-model="trip.name" type="text" ng-change='customer.name=trip.name;'>
<input ng-model="customer.name" type="text">
```